# AssociationTypeMismatch for collection_check_boxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

**Controller**

```
class PlayerProfilesController < InheritedResources::Base

    def show
        @player_profile = PlayerProfile.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

**Model**

```
class PlayerProfile < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :playing_roles, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :player_roles, through: :playing_roles

end

class PlayerRole < ActiveRecord::Base

   has_many :playing_roles, :dependent => :destroy 
   has_many :player_profiles, through: :playing_roles

end

class PlayingRole < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :player_profile
  belongs_to :player_role

end
```

**show.html.erb**

```
<%=collection_check_boxes(:player_profile, :playing_roles, PlayerRole.all, :id, :name)%>
```

[collection_check_boxes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_check_boxes) (docs)

HTML generated for two checkboxes

```
<input id="player_profile_playing_roles_1" name="player_profile[playing_roles][]" type="checkbox" value="1" class="hidden-field">
<span class="custom checkbox checked"></span>
<label for="player_profile_playing_roles_1">Striker</label>

<input id="player_profile_playing_roles_2" name="player_profile[playing_roles][]" type="checkbox" value="2" class="hidden-field">
<span class="custom checkbox"></span>
<label for="player_profile_playing_roles_2">Midfielder</label>
<input name="player_profile[playing_roles][]" type="hidden" value="">
```

It Seems that it show all correctly but when I click on submit button I get this error:
[image]

Comment: Can you add controller action code?

Comment: @user1028100 can you paste full backtrace?

Comment: I believe @MichaelSzyndel was looking for controller action code for #update as well...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, I thought this was complicated but I don't think it is.

You are telling the `collection_check_boxes` to expect `:playing_roles` but then passing it a collection of PlayerRoles via `PlayerRole.all`. That is the mismatch. AssociationTypeMismatch is when you tell an object to associate a Duck but then pass it a Helicopter.

You need to do this:

```
<%= collection_check_boxes(:player_profile, :player_role_ids, PlayerRole.all, :id, :name) %>
```

You tell it to expect `:player_role_ids`, you pass it a collection of `PlayerRole.all` with value method `:id` and text method `:name`.

Then, in the update, it'll save those ids to the `player_role_ids` attribute on Player, causing the associations to build.

See also:
[Rails has_many :through and collection_select with multiple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8239961/rails-has-many-through-and-collection-select-with-multiple)